# How to pass variables to 'text' in racket

Tags: text, geometry, racket-student-languages

I have to create the above image[image: circle with text]

The text inside is variable. What I mean is that I want to pass 2 values to it for display and these values keep changing. 
I am trying this:

`(define (circle-text vx vy)
  (underlay/align "center"
                  "center"
                  (circle 40 "outline" "blue")
                  (text "("vx", "vy")" 14 "blue")))`

But this obviously doesnt work. Please suggest me any better syntax or anything.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Check out `string-append`

Comment: Check out `format` or `~a`

Comment: @BenGreenman this is clearly using 2htdp/image. As such, it's likely that `format` or `~a` is not allowed in the class they are taking.

Comment: I was surprised, but [`format` is actually in the docs for BSL](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28def._htdp-beginner._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._format%29%29). It's included with the rest of the BSL string functions. Now the question is whether students should use it when they see it in the BSL docs

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(text (string-append "(" vx ", " vy ")") 14 "blue")
```

The above works assuming that `vx` and `vy` are already strings. If not, use this:

```
(text (string-append "(" (number->string vx) ", " (number->string vy) ")") 14 "blue")
```

Given that you're using Racket, this is even simpler:

```
(text (format "(~a, ~a)" vx vy) 14 "blue")
```